# Call more than post method in same resource in RestLet framework

Tags: java, restlet

I want more than one post method in the same resource class of RestLet framework as shown below:

```
public class Myclass extends ServerResource {

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(LoginResource.class.getName());

    @Post
    public Representation createUser(final Representation representation) throws IOException {
        ..........................
        ................................
    }

    /**
      * This class will help in creating a person.
      * @return representation Representation
      * @param representation Representation
      * @throws IOException IOException
      */
    @Post
    public Representation createAllUser(final Representation representation) throws IOException {
        ...............
        ...............................
        return new JacksonRepresentation<>("Success");
    }
}
```

How can do it? Please provide some solution according to my problem. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you exactly want to do. What isn't very clear from your question is the way to choose the method to use to handle a `POST` request (call one or another annotated method). Do you want to use a query parameter, an header or something in the payload?

For a query parameter, you can use something at the annotation level, as described below:

```
@Post("?myparam=something")
public Representation createUser(final Representation representation) throws IOException {
```

For the other cases, I think that you should use a single annotated method that handles the routing to the right handling method. Something like that if you want to use a custom header `x-action`:

```
@Post
public Representation handleAction(Representation representation)
                                     throws IOException {
    Series<Header> headers = (Series<Header>)
       getRequestAttributes().get("org.restlet.http.headers");

    String actionHeader = headers.getFirstValue("x-action", "single");
    if ("single".equals(actionHeader)) {
        return handleAction1(representation);
    } else {
        return handleAction2(representation);
    }
}
```

In addition, you can have a look at this link about the way to implement multi actions with method `POST` with REST and Restlet: https://templth.wordpress.com/2015/03/20/handling-multiple-actions-for-a-post-method/.

Hope it helps you,
Thierry